# How to minify angularjs directives with templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created an angularjs module which is having directive with templateUrl.

I have used ngmin to generate code with dependencies. But i want to minify whole js along with html referred  in templateUrl.

Can someone point out some documents or how it can be done using grunt?

```
angular.module('myWidget', [])

.constant('MODULE_VERSION', '0.0.3')


.value('defaults', {
    foo: 'bar'
})


.factory('factoryName', function() {/* stuff here */})


.directive('directiveName', function() {
   return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl  : '/directive.html',
        scope: true,
        controller : 'directiveCtrl',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {

        }
    }

})
.controller('directiveCtrl', function (){

});
```

standalone directive.html page

```
<div>myWidgetDirectiveHtml</div>
```

[Download Demo Files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xy0arrn84nku390/mywidget.zip)

Updated with another approach

Enable CORS in end domiain where js files and directive view are hosted

This will go inside module config

```
 $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        // Allow same origin resource loads.
        'self',
     // Allow loading from our assets domain.Notice the difference between * and   **.
        'https://yourdomain.com/**'
    ]);
```

in directive

do like

```
 templateUrl : "https://yourdomain.com/directive.html"
```

Comment: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify

Comment: Was trying to figure out how uglify can go in to the templateUrl and convert that in javascript templates.

I have updated with my module structure.

Comment: templateUrl is just a string containing the URL of a template. There is nothing to minify in there.

Comment: I'm trying to develop a reusable plugin using angularjs.


For that i have created a module and its directive is using templateUrl rather than template.

lets say my widget filename is mywidget.js hosted in
http://mywidgetcdn.com/mywidget.js

and i'm going to use this in http://maindomain.com

so when i add mywidget.js in maindomain.com, templateUrl is relative to maindomain.com. 

I have attached very basic demo of my module with sample directive html.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want to embed the template as a JS file? Is something like https://github.com/karlgoldstein/grunt-html2js what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Here  what i'm doing is converting html to javascript template and then we can use it along with the directives.

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-html2js');
    grunt.registerTask('build', ['html2js']);
    grunt.registerTask('release', ['html2js']);
    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
       html2js: {
        options: {
            // custom options, see below
        },
        main: {
            src: ['yourhtml.html','another.html'],
            dest: 'templates.js'
        }
      }
    })
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Project Name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-html2js": "~0.1.0"
  }
}
```

Command

`grunt build`

Comment: I know i'm really late here, but I don't get how am I going to reference the right template in the directive if the templates are converted to the js one?